# Django loop through a list of objects in template

Tags: django, list, templates, object, loops

I'm trying to store the results from a query in a list or similar (trying different alternatives), but the one I have got the furthest with is:

```
def index(request):
for post in blog_posts:
        comments_total.setdefault(post.id, []).append(comments.total(post.id))
return render_to_response('blog/index.html', {
'comments': comments_total})
```

In the return-data I get:
{5L: [2], 6L: [1]}

I'm using this code to access:

```
{% if comments %}
{{comments}}<br />
{% for cid in comments %}
{% if cid == post.id %}
{{cid}} - {{comments.cid.0}}<br />
{{cid}} - {{comments.6.0}}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

What it prints out in whole is:

{5L: [2], 6L: [1]}
5 - 
5 - 1

Is there an alternative for how to get all comments for, in this case, a blog, count through the results for each post and return it to the template?

What I'm trying to do is to get a counter for the start-page of a blog.
"You have (X) comments on this post"-kind of thing.

Comment: Are you using any particular module for your commenting system?  Some of them (like Disqus) have built in functions for returning information like this.

Comment: No extra modules. The only module I have is the custom I made for comments and posts, which is fairly simple "load it neatly into the database".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this is in more efficient way "showing counts of comments for each post"

Lets say you have two models `Post` and `Comment`. Just define a `related_name` to the post `ForeignKey` relationship in `Comment` model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments')
    # other fields
```

Then in template you can do:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {{post.comments.count}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I did try this, but it didn't work out. Gives me an "UnboundLocalError" because "comments" was referenced before assignment. Is the related_name taken from any variable which I might have in the model, or just out of the blue?

Comment: Is the error came from model? If yes you might have missed single quotes it should be `related_name='comments'`. No related_name is not taken from any variable, it just defined directly there as a string